# on_open function is failing to run when opening websocket connection?

Tags: python, websocket

I'm trying to use the Alpaca API to read real-time stock data; however, I can't even seem to open a websocket to connect. My current code is:

```
import config
import websocket, json

def on_open(ws):
    print("opened")

socket = "wss://data.alpaca.markets/stream"

ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(socket, on_open=on_open)
ws.run_forever()
```

No errors are thrown, but "opened" never prints; I've tried running the debugger, but the ws.run_forever() command just executes (again, without any error), and then the program ends without any connection. Any thoughts as to what I'm doing wrong? I think I have websockets installed correctly; when I do `pip3 install websockets` I get the following:

```
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
Requirement already satisfied: websockets in c:\users\my_name\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (9.1)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
```

Additionally, I am able to connect through the terminal (therefore, I don't think it's afirewall or local machine issue); it's just running it through Python that seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was originally running the above on Windows.

I switched to a Mac, and everything is working.

Not sure why, but it fixed the issue for me.